# addEventListener not working inside function

Tags: javascript, dom, addeventlistener

I am trying to generate a form based on these settings...

```
let formItems = new Form("form-items", {
        items: [
            { id: "companyName" },
            { id: "documentKey" },
            { id: "documentDate" }
        ],
    });
```

Inside, I generate each input, and try to add an `eventListener`, but it donesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

```
module.exports = function Form(formElementId, options) {

    this.state = {}

    options.items.map(item => {
        renderInput(item.id);
        this.state[item.id] = ""
    })

    function renderInput(id) {

        let html = `<input id="${id}" />`

        document.getElementById(formElementId).innerHTML += html;

        document.getElementById(id).addEventListener("input", (e) => {
            console.log(e);                      // <--------- Doesn't work
            this.state[id] = e.target.value;     // <--------- Doesn't work
            console.log(this.state);             // <--------- Doesn't work
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: check `console` and `document.getElementById(id).length`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of having your variable as template literal, you can just dynamically create an HTML input element and attach to it the event, also instead of add the HTML to using `+=` just have appended to the container

I would use this snippet instead:

```
module.exports = function Form(formElementId, options) {
  this.state = {};
  self = this;
  options.items.map(item => {
    renderInput(item.id);
    this.state[item.id] = "";
  });

  function renderInput(id) {
    let input = document.createElement("input");
    input.setAttribute("id", id);

    document.getElementById(formElementId).append(input);

    input.addEventListener("input", e => {
      self.state[id] = e.target.value;
    });
  }
};
```

Comment: Why does this work vs template literals? Also, `this.state` is undefined? How do I bind it? Do I use `let self = this` and then use `self.state`?

Comment: Why does this work vs template literals: this is caused by not have the div yet add and recognized by JavaScript and the HTML engine, so the variable approach is a native way to have HTML DOM elements,    Also, this.state is undefined: sorry missed that but yes since arrow functions doesn't bind to `this` by default you can just have as normal function or use `self` variable as you stated.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Can you please edit your solution to include the `this` fix, without arrow functions? How would that look?

Comment: I updated this for a quick fix with arrow function, will check later for other options.